# Latest Watir version supports Edge?

Tags: ruby, watir, selenium-edgedriver

I see WATIR supports Edge browser automation in official website. But when I tried to run my existing suite on Edge after setting the path for MicrosoftWebDriver.exe in environment variables I am facing the below error .

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to connect to
>   MicrosoftWebDriver localhost:17556

[image: Unable to Connect to MicrosoftWebDriver localhost:17556]

Below are my version details.

Watir - 6.8.4 
Ruby  - 2.2.6 
Windows 10 64 bit

I even tried using webdrivers gem of titusfortner. But, no success webdrivers gem is not downloading MicrosoftWebDriver.exe into .webdrivers folder in my users directory.

[image]

I wanted to know whether I have anything wrong in my set up to trigger edge browser. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the issue resolved. We have to download the right version of Microsoft WebDriver.

Go to Start > Settings > System > About and locate the number next to OS Build on the screen. This is your build number. Having the correct version of WebDriver for your build ensures it runs correctly.

Get the right version of driver at [WebDriver - Microsoft Edge Development](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)